# Add "View on Google Maps" custom button on Google map programmatically

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to customize and add a google maps map in my website.

I'm able to add it programmatically using google maps JS api, the map is correctly shown and everything with the below code ([**see fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/5L2j492m/)):

```
function initialize() {
    var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    var map_options = {
        disableDefaultUI : false,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.9100711,12.5359979),
        zoom: 17,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
        scrollwheel : false,
        zoomControl : true,
        streetViewControl : false,
        scaleControl : true,
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map : map,
            position : new google.maps.LatLng(41.9100711,12.5359979),
            title : "Title"
    });
    var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content : "marker content"
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(){
        info.open(map,marker);
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Now I'd like to add the "Open in google maps" button:

[image]

in order to let the user browse the map and get the direction to the place the marker is pointing.

I'm reading the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide), but I'm only able to find "url examples", and nothing related to JS to configure my map.

Anyone has any kind of suggestion?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing the actual problem is adding the button to the map. You need to create a custom control that looks like a button and has a click handler, and you need to add it to maps controls array:

```
var gotoMapButton = document.createElement("div");
gotoMapButton.setAttribute("style", "margin: 5px; border: 1px solid; padding: 1px 12px; font: bold 11px Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF; cursor: pointer;");
gotoMapButton.innerHTML = "Open Google Maps";
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(gotoMapButton);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(gotoMapButton, "click", function () {
    var url = 'https://www.google.com/maps?q=' + encodeURIComponent(marker.getPosition().toUrlValue());
    // you can also hard code the URL
    window.open(url);
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5L2j492m/2/)

---

There is [an official example as well](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom).